# Non key columns in mining model must be set to PredictOnly

Tags: sql, ssas

I am getting this error when I am trying to add additional column as an input value to my mining model. It says non key columns must be predict only. But I have predict only column which is what I wanted to predict. I will add a screen shot here for your reference. If I change IsSeason column as ignore or predict only it works fine. But my purpose is to take IsSeason column as an input to my model.

[image]

Comment: This is how the [Microsoft Time Series](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174923.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) algorithm works. The link shows that the time series requires: a single key time column, a predictable column and an optional series key column. That's all the input for that algorithm

Comment: Then what is the point of having 'input' type for the time series.

Comment: I don't work in microsoft, so I can't answer that. It seems like they enable every option available for other mining algorithms, doesn't mean that they are allowed in that one in particular

Comment: now this is getting interesting. I deployed my model in remote server and i got above error. But when i deploy it in my local server it takes 'IsSeason' as an input and model deployed perfectly. I tried it just now. Any thought, which could be the reason for the error?

Comment: My remote server is sql version 12.0 while my local server is 13.0. May be they are allowing 'input' types in Timeseries for the latest version

Comment: I upgraded remote server to 13.0 as well. But still inputs are not allowed. This is really unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I have used SQL server developer version 2016 in my local machine and my remote machine has SQL server standard version 2016. In MSDN they clearly says, developer version suppoerts Advanced corporate business intelligence.

https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/overview.aspx